# React-Bootstrap and/or Bootstrap with Webpack

Tags: webpack, react-bootstrap

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to use bootstrap with React and the Webpack build. I'd like to use Bootstrap's grid layout and various features (appears that react-bootstrap offers all of the features of bootstrap?) and wondering what's the best way of setting this up.

For example, I've tried the following with the normal bootstrap approach as well as react-bootstrap's components, but they don't seem to work. Also, how would you recommend going about using the css reset to normalize everything? Thank you, in advance, for your help.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import mui from 'material-ui';
  import style from './style.scss';
  import Navigation from './Navigation';
  import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        /* normal bootstrap -- doesn't work */
        <div className="container">

          /* react-bootstrap which also doesn't work */
          <Grid>
            <Row className="show-grid">
              <Col md={6} mdPush={6}><code>&lt;{'Col md={6} mdPush={6}'} /&gt;</code></Col>
              <Col md={6} mdPull={6}><code>&lt;{'Col md={6} mdPull={6}'} /&gt;</code></Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>

          <Navigation />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm currently importing the react-bootstrap css at my startup.

In app.js (where you'd call ReactDOM.render):

```
// Import the CSS reset, which HtmlWebpackPlugin transfers to the build folder
import 'sanitize.css/lib/sanitize.css';
import '!!style-loader!css-loader!./vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

sanitize does what normaliser does but better apparently.